# how to remove column names from flat file and replace with "header record information".. (filename, timestamp etc..)

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file I need to replace the column names with header record information. I tried inserting the header with a data flow step of using a OLE DB source to flat file destination where I select the information from variables and insert into flat file. that works fine but I need to now insert the data.

Should I insert the data first then change the column headers to the header information for the file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do it, but it really is a matter of preference which you pick.

1. Do what you have done already (use a data flow task to populate the header information). Next, create another connection manager for the file that has all of the column information defined. On the general tab, indicate that there is one header row to skip and uncheck the box for column names in the first data row. Then, create a data flow task to populate the file with data and, use this connection manager. So when your package runs, the first data flow task needs to run first and write the header row. When that is complete, the second one should run and populate the file with data.
2. Write the data to the file using a data flow task, and then have a script task that replaces the column names with the header row (or if you don't have column names there, just inserts the header row at the beginning of the file).

Comment: Did you use method #1?

Comment: Yes method 1. A lot easier. I am not familiar with Script Tasks yet, Thanks Jeremy... I have 3 separate flat file connection managers pointing to same file. First HDR record inserted, then DTL record and TRL records.. work perfect. Thanks again!